# ng2-datepicker + not supported in angular 4

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular2-forms

I am trying to upgrade from angular 2.4.0 to angular 4. When i tried it, i found following peer dependency errors:

Tried installing latest datepicker:

```
npm install ng2-datepicker –save
```

Got following error:

```
npm WARN ng2-datepicker@1.8.3 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^2.4.0 but none 
was installed.
```

Tried installing latest tooltip:

```
npm install ngx-tooltip –save
```

Got following error:

```
npm WARN ngx-tooltip@0.0.9 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
```

How do i use ng2-datepicker/ngx-tooltip with angular 4? Or is there any other module for datepicker and tooltip which can work for angular 4.

Comment: those are just warning, you should check whether it works for you by running up you app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your `package.json` and make sure you have this:

```
"@angular/core": "^4.0.1",
"@angular/forms": "^4.0.1",
```

That would mean that your migration to version 4 (at least on those modules) has been succesful.

And for datepicker, use `ng2-datetime`. Works like a charm.

For installing it:

```
npm install --save ng2-datetime
```

- npm Docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datetime
- github Docs: https://github.com/nkalinov/ng2-datetime
- Documentation: https://nkalinov.github.io/ng2-datetime/

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `{{data.lastModifiedDate|date:'MMM dd,yyyy'}}` to formate your date